# Relativistic correction of Coulomb's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

I am attempting to describe Coulomb's law but with the delay one would get because of the light speed limit. I am aware one could do that using Maxwell's equations because they are relativistic, but my aim is to do it with Coulomb's law.

My attempt was to describe the electric field at some point $\vec{r}$ as the sum (later integral) of the electric field originating from every point. In other words:

$$\vec{E}(t,\vec{r}) = \int d^3x \vec{E}_\vec{x} (t,\vec{r})$$

where $\vec{E}_\vec{x}(t,\vec{r})$ is the electric field density originating from point $\vec{x}$

But in reality a particle at position $\vec{r}$ and time $t$ is not affected by the electric field density at point $\vec{x}$ at time $t$, but rather at time $t - \frac{|\vec{r} - \vec{x}|}{c}$, i.e, the time light takes to reach point $\vec{r}$ from $\vec{x}$.

So instead the electric field would be:

$$\vec{E}(t,\vec{r}) = \int d^3x \vec{E}_\vec{x} (t - \frac{|\vec{r} - \vec{x}|}{c},\vec{r})$$

Now I stop here because the calculations became intensive and I've lost my intuition. My question is: is this approach correct?. I know that there are other contributions of the electric fields that include more than the Coulomb force.

A sample of what the electric field would be for a point like charge with coordinates $\vec{r_0}(t)$:

$$\vec{E}_\vec{x} (t,\vec{r}) = k_e \frac{\vec{q}}{(\vec{r}-\vec{x})^3}(\vec{r}-\vec{x})\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{r_0}(t))$$

So am I on the correct track?

Comment: There are already the equations of the retarted electric field

Comment: it's awkward to use $\vec r - \vec x$: can't remember which is the primed coordinate.  Try: $\vec r-\vec r'$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations

Comment: The function $\vec{E}_{\vec{x}}$ is more complicated, it depends on velocity and acceleration of the source charge in the past. This can be derived from Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: is this approach correct?

No, this approach is not correct. It is fundamentally flawed.

You cannot get a relativistic version of a force law simply by adding a propagation delay to it. Relativity is more than just a finite speed of light.

With this approach the forces will have the wrong magnitude and even the wrong direction. You will get different frames where the resulting accelerations of charged particles will not properly coincide. This will introduce special reference frames and violate the principle of relativity.

If you fix those problems then you will get ordinary classical electromagnetism

Answer (score 0):

EM textbooks solve this by Lorentz transforming the Coulomb potential (or Coulomb E field), and then changing the rest frame time to the time variable in the moving frame.